# Firebase notifications stop working on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have read a lot of answers of Firebase notifications on Android but none of them solve my problem.

I have an Android application with Firebase installed and the Firebase project is created and configured. The dependencies are included in my project and I have the service but I don't receive any notification.

The code of my service is:

```
package es.angelcasas.meteoferrolterra;

import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String s) {
        super.onNewToken(s);
        Log.e("NEW_TOKEN",s);
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
        // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
        // Instance ID token to your app server.

        //TODO: Send Token to Server
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        Log.d("MENSAJE", "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        // Check if message contains a data payload.
    }
}
```

My AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="es.angelcasas.meteoferrolterra">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icono"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/icono"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MenuPrincipal"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Noticias" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Radares" />
        <activity
            android:name=".BuscarActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Radar" />
        <activity android:name=".Avisos"></activity>

        <!-- [START firebase_service] -->
        <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService" android:stopWithTask="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <!-- [END firebase_service] -->
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "es.angelcasas.meteoferrolterra"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.4'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I also downloaded the google-services.json file.

If I go to Cloud Messaging and send a new notification it nevers arrives...

The most strange this is that when I tried this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u9vWzCC0JKU

The notifications works ok but then they stop working even when I restart the whole project...

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you haven't create any notification in 'onMessageReceived' method where you are receiving push notification message

Answer (score 1):

You can create push notification using following code. change the key-pair values with yours

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    Log.d("MENSAJE", "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    // Prepare Notification.
    ShowNotification(remoteMessage);

}

void ShowNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
{
    String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";// The id of the channel.

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new     NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
Random random = new Random();
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), random.nextInt(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round));
builder.setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getData().get("title")); //the "title" value you sent in your notification
builder.setContentText(remoteMessage.getData().get("body"));
builder.setSubText(remoteMessage.getData().get("subTitle"));
builder.setAutoCancel(true);
builder.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID);
builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
builder.setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);

try
{
    Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
    r.play();
} catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
{

    /* Create or update. */
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,
            "title",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
}
//Creating unique id for each notification
int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
notificationManager.notify(id, builder.build());
}
```

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong.... your code works but notifications only arrived when I open and close the application....

Comment: I would suggest using getData() instead of getNotification() inside your push notification object. In getData() the notification is received & shown regardless if the app is in foreground/background.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you aware about Topic and InstanceId based messaging.

I believe for testing purpose you are trying with Topic-based broadcast message.

So, Please make sure you have subscribed the topic in Activity or Application.

```
 FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("Your_Topic");
```

Comment: Where do I have to put this code? In the onNewTokenMethod? Thanks

Comment: Create a class which extends Application and define it in Manifest file. Override the onCreate method and put the above code with the topic you want to publish the message.

Answer (score 0):

After days of reading tutorials and hundreds of stackoverflow threads I notice that I didn't include my app in the protected apps list of my phone... The OS was killing my app.

Everything is working now!

Thank you all guys!